# How to appendChild as first row in tbody and have their own tbody using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, append

I need to append data from json as row in a table. i need to append row with id="project" as first row in their own tbody. if new project detected, new tbody will created and project and task will have their own tbody. if row id is "task" then it will created after the project row. How can i do this?

Json data =

```
var jason = {"projects":[{"projName":"1","task_data":[{"taskName":"1","task_detail_data":[{"hr_Sun":"0.00","hr_Mon":"0.00","hr_Tue":"0.00","hr_Wed":"0.00","hr_Thu":"0.00","hr_Fri":"0.00","hr_Sat":"0.00"}]},{"taskName":"1","task_detail_data":[{"hr_Sun":"0.00","hr_Mon":"0.00","hr_Tue":"0.00","hr_Wed":"0.00","hr_Thu":"0.00","hr_Fri":"0.00","hr_Sat":"0.00"}]}]}]}
```

Code to Display in Table =

```
function displayData(data) {

var json = JSON.parse(data);

for (let i = 0; i < json.projects.length; i++) {

    var tb = document.getElementById("table");
    var x = document.createElement("tbody");
    x.setAttribute("id", "Section");
    x.setAttribute("class", "theBody");
    tb.appendChild(x);

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute("id", "Project");
    tr.setAttribute("class", "p_name");
    tr.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #e8e8e8; color:black");
    x.appendChild(tr);
    
    //add data
        
    for (let j = 0; j < json.projects[i].task_data.length; j++) {

            var trow = document.createElement('tr');
            trow.setAttribute("id", "Task");
            trow.setAttribute("class", "val");
            x.appendChild(trow);   

            //add data
    }
}

}
```

Supposedly it will work nicely, however, when i run the code, the row will be unorganized, and sometimes body will own wrong project and task, and sometimes no child at all. This is wrong.

Please help. Thanks

**This is what i suppose to get
[image]
**But this is what i get (noted that A:1 B:2 C:3)
[image]
**This is from Dev Tool. Noted that first two tbody didnt capture its own project and task and left empty
[image]

Comment: Not clear. Can you sketch out a sample initial state of the table, then states for different types of insertions?

Comment: i added few picture for your understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Organise your code using [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) .

```js
const json = {
  "projects": [{
    "projName": "1",
    "task_data": [{
      "taskName": "Task 1",
      "task_detail_data": [{
        "hr_Sun": "0.00",
        "hr_Mon": "0.00",
        "hr_Tue": "0.00",
        "hr_Wed": "0.00",
        "hr_Thu": "0.00",
        "hr_Fri": "0.00",
        "hr_Sat": "0.00"
      }]
    }, {
      "taskName": "Task 2",
      "task_detail_data": [{
        "hr_Sun": "0.00",
        "hr_Mon": "0.00",
        "hr_Tue": "0.00",
        "hr_Wed": "0.00",
        "hr_Thu": "0.00",
        "hr_Fri": "0.00",
        "hr_Sat": "0.00"
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

//---- Task, Project and App components
class Task extends React.Component {

 render() {
   return (
     <tr className="val">
       <td>{this.props.name}</td>
       <td>{JSON.stringify(this.props.details)}</td>
     </tr>
   )
 }
}

Task.defaultProps= {details:{}};
 // Project component
class Project extends React.Component {

   render() {
     return (
       <tbody className="p_name" style={{backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8', color:'black'}}>

        {this.props.tasks.map((t,i) => 
          <Task key={i} name={t.taskName} details={t.task_detail_data} />
        )}

       </tbody>
     )
   }

}

Project.defaultProps = {tasks: []};

   // App component
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
     return (
       <table>

          {json.projects.map(p => 
            <Project tasks={p.task_data}  />
          )}

       </table>
     )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector('section') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<section>
  
  
  </section>
```

Comment: As you can note, just you need to import two scripts at the <head > of your page

Comment: Thanks but i believe this cannot be applied on my code.

Comment: you can .. believe me .. اتصل بي بالسكايب سأعينك إن وجدت وقتا 
abdennour.tm

Comment: how can i contact you personally, abdennour?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything is caused by my own mistakes. the positioning of each function/process(not included in example) is wrong, thats why it didnt result nicely.

The code is correct. Thanks all

**Btw,for early comment by /anonymous/ that i should use prepend, i would like to mark him as the answer but he is gone. soo...

this should be his answer and it is correct

```
function displayData(data) {

var json = JSON.parse(data);

for (let i = 0; i < json.projects.length; i++) {

    var tb = document.getElementById("table");
    var x = document.createElement("tbody");
    x.setAttribute("id", "Section");
    x.setAttribute("class", "theBody");
    tb.appendChild(x);

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute("id", "Project");
    tr.setAttribute("class", "p_name");
    tr.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #e8e8e8; color:black");
    x.prepend(tr);

    //add data

    for (let j = 0; j < json.projects[i].task_data.length; j++) {

            var trow = document.createElement('tr');
            trow.setAttribute("id", "Task");
            trow.setAttribute("class", "val");
            x.appendChild(trow);   

            //add data
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You can move ` var tb = document.getElementById("table");` out of the loop.